# EvalError: Possible side-effect in debug-evaluate in Google Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

I get this error in the Chrome console every time I try to evaluate an expression.

```
EvalError: Possible side-effect in debug-evaluate
```

What could be causing it?

Comment: same here, I think new chrome update caused the problem. I tried in different browser. it works without any error. I think should add google-chome tag.

Comment: I also just started getting this issue. Is your website public, can you link to it so we can try it there too? Mine is sadly not. As soon as I type any character at all into the Chrome dev console, I get an error caught not through the usual console.error, but via window.onerror. `EvalError: Possible side-effect in debug-evaluate`. This issue does not happen in Firefox.

Comment: My version is `Version 102.0.5005.61 (Official Build) (x86_64)` can you share your Chrome version?

Comment: Are you sure its Next.js, we don't use Next.js, but we are using Vue.js 3

Answer (score 34):

I think I found the issue, reading through a [discussion](https://github.com/electron/electron/issues/34350) on an electron issues board.

It could potentially be caused by this: [[inspector] Add custom error dispatch machinery for debug evaluate.](https://chromium-review.googlesource.com/c/v8/v8/+/3557234/)

And hopefully fixed in this: [[inspector] Don't trigger window.onerror with side-effects disabled.](https://chromium-review.googlesource.com/c/v8/v8/+/3660253)

> This was an oversight in https://crrev.com/c/3557234, which led to a really weird developer experience: once a `window.onerror` handler was installed, typing into the Console or other side-effect free debug evaluations triggered this handler.

Comment: Until this is fixed, it looks like `event.defaultPrevented` is true for the ErrorEvent caused by this behavior. Filtering those out in my `onerror` handler works well enough for me.

Answer (score 14):

The website you are inspecting contains an `onerror` event listener.

A new bug in the latest version of Chrome triggers this event every time an expression is evaluated in DevTools. This includes live expressions and the console.

If this is your own website, add this line of JavaScript to your event listener to ignore any errors triggered outside of a script, where `script` is the second argument of the event listener function:

```
if(!script.endsWith(".js")) return;
```

Note that this will only work for external JavaScript (in `.js` files), in the case of JavaScript embedded in HTML `<script>` tags, it will disable your event listener entirely.

---

If this is not your website, you can temporarily disable the event listener in DevTools, like this:

1. At the top of DevTools, open the "Elements" tab
2. Press "»", on the right of "Styles", "Computed", "Layout"
3. Choose "Event listeners"
4. Find and expand "onerror"
5. Click "Remove"

This will remove the event listener, but the issue will return after you refresh the page.

Hopefully the next version of Chrome will fix this bug.

Comment: Perfect. This works in `onerror` listeners in browser extensions too. Especially if using an expression in the console to see the results of chrome.storage api ...