# Chrome: EvalError: Possible side-effect in debug

Tags: javascript

Just load this page and try something to write in chrone debug console!
On 'onerror' raised error 'Possible side-effect in debug-evaluate'!
Chrome version 102.0.5005.63
Edge OK!

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">

        <script type="text/javascript">
                //error message
                window.onerror = function (msg, url, line, col, error) {
                    console.log(error);
                    if (confirm(error.name + ':' + error.message)) {
                        location.reload(true);
                        return true;
                    }
                };
        </script>

        <div >
            <div >
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hello. You did not include the error that you say happens. Anyway, I run the code on jsfiddle and it works.

Comment: Possibly a duplicate, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72396527/evalerror-possible-side-effect-in-debug-evaluate-in-next-js/72402135

Comment: You should load this page and try to write in chrome debug console.

Comment: I did, but I realized I use Firefox so I'm unlikely to run into a Chrome issue. You might be able to find your answer on the link I attached.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: It is impossible to write anything in Chrome debug (DevTools) console, 'onerror' event raise an error - 'Possible side-effect in debug-evaluate'.

Comment: This has been fixed in Chromium: https://chromium.googlesource.com/v8/v8/+/ac5096a0daa6bd7cb3b8aa350eaddc3a67f3480e

Comment: Does this answer your question? [EvalError: Possible side-effect in debug-evaluate in Next.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72396527/evalerror-possible-side-effect-in-debug-evaluate-in-next-js)

Comment: Yes, a've tried with cromium :). I'm just waiting for Chrome & Edge Chromium upgrade.