# how to ignore or fix a runtime error unique to chrome and next.js

Tags: next.js, google-chrome-devtools

I'm using a boilerplate next.js template provided by this commmand:

```
npx create-next-app .
```

The error I get when I try to type anything on the chrome devtools console:

```
Unhandled Runtime Error
EvalError: Possible side-effect in debug-evaluate
```

My question: Is there a way to ignore or completely fix this type of error?

First: The supposed "[duplicate solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72396527/evalerror-possible-side-effect-in-debug-evaluate-in-next-js)" is a closed question with no accepted answer. The only response doesn't really offer a solution.

What I have tried

- Tested on both Microsoft Edge and Mozilla Firefox. They don't seem to have this problem. My chrome version is: `Version 102.0.5005.63 (Official Build) (64-bit)`.
- Tested create-react-app and a normal js/html app and both don't seem to trigger errors. I'm concluding that this error is unique to the nextjs/chrome combo.
- Same problem happens on other windows computers. This means that this problem is possibly global
- Disabling the "eager evaluation" option in the chrome devtools seems to have solved the problem. I'm still looking for a solution that doesn't involve the removal of this feature.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error seems to have been fixed in the latest chrome version. If it happens again, you can disable the "eager evaluation" option in the chrome devtools to fix the issue.